# QItemDelegate: painting an unwanted QCheckBox

Tags: qt, qitemdelegate, qabstracttablemodel

I have an editable model, which inherits QAbstractTableModel. Also have a custom delegate to go with it.  This is my first editable model, and I think I'm missing something.  I'm pretty much following the examples found at Nokia.  My model tells the delegate that the data is editable via flags().  When I do this, it draws a QSpinBox in the cell.

Underlying model is a simple std::map.  The key is days, the value is a rate.
Generally, what is painted in any editable cell, is a QCheckBox, but is ghosted out, then the data.  If I double-click on the value, I am shown the editor, which happens to be a custom widget based on QDoubleSpinbox.

```
Qt::ItemFlags my_model_t::flags( const QModelIndex& index ) const
{
    if ( !index.isValid() ) {
        return Qt::NoItemFlags;
    }

    if ( index.column() == col_rates ) {
        return QAbstractItemModel::flags( index ) | Qt::ItemIsEditable;
    }

    return QAbstractItemModel::flags( index );
}

QVariant my_model_t::data( const QModelIndex& index, int role ) const
{
    if ( !index.isValid() ) {
        return QVariant();
    }

    if ( role == Qt::DisplayRole || Qt::EditRole ) {

        if ( static_cast<int>( rates.size() ) <= index.row() ) {
            return QVariant();
        }

        int day = vec[index.row()];

        if ( index.column() == col_days ) {
            return day;
        } else if ( index.column() == col_rates ) {

            std::map<int, double>::const_iterator it = rates.find( day );
            if ( it != rates.end() ) {
                return (*it).second;
            }
        }
    }

    return QVariant();
}

QWidget* my_delegate_t::createEditor( QWidget* parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem& /*option*/, const QModelIndex& index ) const
{
    gui_spinbox* editor = new gui_spinbox( parent );

    if ( index.column() == col_rate ) {
        const my_model_t* model = static_cast<my_model_t*>( index.model() );
    }

    return editor;
}

void my_delegate_t::setEditorData( QWidget* editor, const QModelIndex& index ) const
{
    double value    = index.model()->data( index, Qt::EditRole ).toDouble();
    gui_spinbox* spin_box   = static_cast<gui_spinbox*>( editor );
    if ( spin_box ) {
        spin_box->setValue( value );
    }
}

void my_delegate_t::setModelData( QWidget* editor, QAbstractItemModel* model, const QModelIndex& index ) const
{
    gui_spinbox* spin_box   = static_cast<gui_spinbox*>( editor );
    if ( spin_box ) {
        double value = spin_box->value();
        model->setData( index, value, Qt::EditRole );
    }
}

void my_delegate_t::updateEditorGemoetry( QWidget* editor, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& /*index*/ ) const
{
    editor->setGeometry( option.rect );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not pretty sure about your problem. Do you want to paint a `QCheckBox`?

In your `createEditor` method, you created an editor use `QSpinbox` but in the *Title* you said it was unwanted.

If you want to be shown an editor based on an `QCheckBox` when you double clicked an item you just create a `checkBox` in the `createEditor` method and use `checkBox` in `setEditorData` and `setModelData`.

Comment: Whew -- I gotta stop drinking at work.  the QCheckBox is unwanted -- the QSpinBox (during edit) is wanted.  

From what I can tell, the damage is done when I reimplmenet flags() in the model... but of course, I have to do this to get the QSpinBox bit to work.